# useContext import problem and props in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I want to import Image from Data.js using useContext hooks the image stored in local storage is not working while when i provide an url of internet it will work.

```
 import iphone from '../Images/iphone.png';
const Data = [
    {
        name:"Apple iphone 12",
        price:'$999',
        colour: 'red',
        item: '1'   ,
        image:{iphone}    
        // image:"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71+17bVYHxL._SX522_.jpg"     
    }
]

export default Data;
```

CardIamge Component:

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import { Iimage } from '../App';
import iphone from '../Images/iphone.png';
// import {Iimage} from './Card';

function CardImage(props) {
    const contextimage = useContext(Iimage)
    return (
        <div>
          <img src={contextimage} alt="" style={{width:"150px" , height:"174px"}} />        
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardImage
```

Card.js Component:

```
import React,{createContext} from 'react'
import '../Components/Card.css'
import CardInfo from './CardInfo';
import CardImage from './CardImage';
// import Data from "./Data";

const Card = (props) =>{
  
    return(
        <>
        <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col extra-mob-align">
            <CardImage />
        </div>
        <CardInfo />
      </div>
    </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Card;
// export {Iimage}
```

I have added all the code related to above problem.

Comment: can you share your folder structure ?

Comment: @Eran I have updated the code.